# First query slow but others fast

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework-core

Have an application, runninging in Azure using EF Core 5.0 and am noticing strange performance issues. At first I thought it was a query problem, and granted it does involve several joins. Have extracted the SQL query that Entity Framework is issuing and looked at the query plan. No missing indexes.  Did see one index scan, but the query itself runs in 4-5 seconds. However, when run via EF and if either the first time it runs or after coming back to in a few min, its very slow, as in over a minute.  When its slow like this, its not as though this is the first query period, as other queries are being done when other pages are requested.  The query is being returned to a grid that is using paging, and about 100 of 700 of the results are being returned.  What could be causing this?  I dont think its simply an issue with the query.  How can one reduce this lag time?

Comment: How many entities registered in Model? EF Core can slowdown during first Model initialisation.

Comment: You need to figure out what the lag time _is_ before you can reduce it. Are these rows very wide? Is there a really low amount of memory? The lag could be loading the data from disk when it is no longer in memory. When the query is slow you need to figure out what it's waiting on (`sys.dm_exec_requests` -> `blocking_session_id` / `wait_type` and `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats` for the executing session).

Comment: Could also not be the database at all. Maybe rendering a complex grid is slow the first time? Does it get any better if you just render text or only put a few columns in the grid? I feel like you haven't narrowed down the source of the issue. "I usually get to New York in 3 hours, but sometimes it takes 5! What's wrong with my car?" Actually it was heavy traffic at rush hour, or an accident, or construction, or you stopped to pee 14 times. Not a problem with the car's engine.

Comment: Enable trace logs for EF. There can be few possible issues - establishing initial connection (can be fixed with warm up request and connection pool settings), EF Core initial load (can be fixed with Compiled models + native AOT/R2R deployment). This can be db issue - for example something wrong with query plans.